# Did my LED luminaire fail because of an underpowered driver?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led

My LED luminaire has recently stopped working. First it started flickering, then stopped altogether, so that instead of the proper amount of light I get an extremely faint glow.

Taking it apart, here is the driver:

[image]

and here is the sticker and connector of the LED assembly:

[image]

(the Hebrew says: "Manufacturer: Tektonics, China")

My questions:

1. Could the cause of failure be the apparent wattage mismatch between the driver and the LED assembly? The luminaire was working fine for a while (before I was even in the apartment it's in, and for no less than 1.5 years overall).
2. Which part is malfunctioning - the driver or the LED assembly? I could theoretically replace that part instead of buying a completely new luminaire.

Comment: Were they bought together as part of the same kit? If so, just send them back. That is a total mis-match, no matter how you slice it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: They were not bought by me, and I have nowhere to send them. Yes, they were bought together, I'm pretty certain.

Comment: Actually, my guess would be the driver. The OP stated that it started flickering before dying. If the LEDs were killed by excessive voltage, I’d expect it to just die.

Comment: @DoxyLover: So, do you think it's worth the shot to try and buy a 40W driver, check whether it can replace the old one? Something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32624852901.html) maybe?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the label on the light is wrong. If you open the light and count how many LEDs it has in series, multiply by about 3.2V each, that will give you an idea of the intended voltage. If it has 196 LEDs I will bet on 14 strings of 14 LEDs in series, for a nominal voltage of 44.8V.

Comment: @einpoklum yes, except you'll need to choose a unit with appropriate current and voltage values for this unit.  *Whatever those may be*...   anyway in North America my advice would be to toss out the unit, as the label of a NRTL is not found anywhere on it. CE and CCC are commonly faked marks.   Our code requires using approved equipment.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine: I'm not in North America :-P

Comment: @bobflux: Is there any danger in opening up the LED assembly (when it's unplugged of course)?

Comment: If it is unplugged for more than a few minutes, no danger besides the usual sharp metal edges and the dog swallowing screws that fall on the floor

Comment: @einpoklum Should be safe then!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the labels on the driver & LEDs are correct, then that driver/LED pair is completely mismatched.
The LEDs are (apparently) rated for a constant *voltage* input (9V) while the driver is rated to provide a constant *current* output (600mA).
The driver will adjust its output voltage between 40V and 50V to try to achieve this constant 600mA current. However your LEDs are expecting almost 4.5A!
It's a wonder that that this pair *ever* worked at all (if the labelling is correct).

If you want to try to resurrect this device (rather than just throwing it out and buying a better one), you might follow bobflux's comment on your question to open it up and count the number of LEDs in each string to calculate approximately what voltage they're expecting - and from there figure out if the labelling is incorrect or if you can just look for a new 600mA 40-50V constant current driver like the old one.

Comment: If the LEDs are expecting 4.5A, how could a .6A current have lit them up to a reasonable brightness?

Comment: LEDs have a wide functional range of operation. It may be that at 4+ Amps this one would be unreasonably bright. Or it may be mislabeled as some commenters suspect - that's hard to know without testing the device.

Comment: @einpoklum because with constant-*voltage* (i.e. normal) power supplies, they are not police, it isn't their job to prevent you from overloading them.  If you draw more current than they are rated for, they will often deliver it, and then blow a fuse or suffer thermal damage.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs are current sensitive devices. Virtually all modern LED controls (drivers) control the current provided to the LED, because that does not lead to [thermal runaway](https://www.candlepowerforums.com/threads/what-is-thermal-runaway-and-why-does-it-happen.379974/) as controlling the voltage to the LED can and does.

**If** the label on the LED part is right, they expect to handle up to 4.44 Amps. (40W / 9V = 4.44A) Most LED drivers are voltage-capable, current limiting - so the driver can put out "as much as" 40-50 volts, but probably puts out 600 mA (0.6A) at **whatever voltage that happens to end up**, so long as it's **less than** 40-50 volts. The voltage varies with the temperature of the LEDs, but by controlling the current, not the voltage, that's not a problem.

As such, suspect the driver. It's almost always the driver. And you can probably make the light a lot brighter (with a different driver); or you can run it at considerably less current and extend its useful life, particularly if it was bright enough at 0.6A input.